# jqGrid - inlineedit - want to change total on change amount value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using inlineEdit Row with jqGrid. I am working on my demo link. http://jsfiddle.net/yzu1prw1/1/

I want to update Total on change of Amount or Tax amount. I am not sure, how to do it.

```
jsfiddle.net/yzu1prw1/1/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/hrzf03xh/2/ uses the following implementation of `aftersavefunc`

```
aftersavefunc: function (rowid) {
    var $self = $(this),
        item = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
        total = (parseFloat(item.amount) + parseFloat(item.tax)).toFixed(2);

    $self.jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "total", total);
    $self.focus();
}
```

I used for the demo [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), the fork which I develop, and which I recommend you to use, but in general the same trick will work with old version of jqGrid. You should be only carefully in the usage of `getLocalRow`, which is the best choice in case of editing local data (`datatype: "local"`), but you should be replaced to `getRowData` in case of usage `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for you reply. Your demo update value after save. I want to change value on blur from textbox. 

I found another way of doing it for each column with following code.
`editoptions: { 
                                dataEvents: 
                                [
                                { type: 'change', fn: function(e) { myfunction(e); } },

                                ]} `

This looks better for me. If you can help with another alternate option then will be great.

Comment: @RidvanShaikh: Sorry, but you should clear describe what you want! I can't spend my time in writing more and more demos. If you makes `total` column **not editable** then you can do the same like in my code `$self.jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "total", total);` inside of `change` handler. If you want to hold the column editable, you can access the input field by id and use `$("#" + rowid +"_total").val(newValue)`. You can get the rowid by `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")`.

Comment: Sorry buddy but i have wrote in my question. I want to do this on change. Anyway, thanks for you help. Getting id help me to process more and really thanks for your help.

Comment: You wrote "update Total on change of Amount or Tax amount". the demo which I posted do this. You are welcome!